# React native udp - dgram.createSocket('udp4') error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying to use react-native-udp library. 
 I use expo and the android studio emulator. 
 I used this manual to install this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-udp 
 However, an error occurs when trying to create a socket. [Emulator screen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEAmQ.png) 
 Code from the App.js:

```
function App() {

var PORT = 50000;
var HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
var address = server.address();
console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" +
address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
console.log('Message',  message);
});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);

}
export default App;
```

**Any ideas? It is not a undefined error...** 
Full error output:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'Sockets.createSocket')
>   - node_modules\react-native-udp\UdpSocket.js:58:7 in UdpSocket
>   - node_modules\react-native-udp\UdpSockets.js:10:35 in exports.createSocket
>   * App.js:11:0 in App
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10696:27 in renderWithHooks
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13481:6 in mountIndeterminateComponent
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36 in invokeGuardedCallback
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20488:8 in beginWork$$1
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19370:24 in performUnitOfWork
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
>   * [native code]:null in renderRoot
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
>   * [native code]:null in runRootCallback
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
>   - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21822:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23042:20 in ReactNativeRenderer.render
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:52:52 in renderApplication
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:116:10 in runnables.appKey.run
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:197:26 in runApplication
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
>   * [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>
> Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
>   - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:645:36 in warningWithoutStack
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18056:16 in callback
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7595:16 in callCallback
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7639:19 in commitUpdateEffects
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7630:22 in commitUpdateQueue
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17116:10 in commitLifeCycles
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20002:23 in commitLayoutEffects
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36 in invokeGuardedCallback
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19768:10 in commitRootImpl
>   * [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
>   - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19590:4 in commitRoot
>   * [native code]:null in commitRoot
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
>   * [native code]:null in runRootCallback
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
>   - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21822:15 in scheduleRootUpdate
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23042:20 in ReactNativeRenderer.render
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:52:52 in renderApplication
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:116:10 in runnables.appKey.run
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:197:26 in runApplication
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
>   * [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

1. Link the library manually in your RN project.

```
yarn link react-native-udp
```

2. Update your pods

```
pod install
```

3. Build for android and ios respectively.